# in React, are there any problems using Set() in a component state?

Tags: javascript, set, reactjs

are there limitations on what sort of objects that can be kept in a component's `state`? would be very nice to use `Set()`, but don't know if that's a good idea (although it appears to be legal).

```jsx
var Com = new React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    { set: new Set() }
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    let set = this.state.set;
    set.add( this.props.someAttribute );
    this.setState( { set: set } );
  },
  ...
});
```

the reason this feels wrong is:

1. it appears React attempts to protects its component `state`, and
2. if so, probably uses `Object.freeze()`).

if these assumptions are correct, and knowing that `Object.freeze()` does not freeze `Set()` or `Map()`, it might be that using them undermines React's ability to protect its component `state`.

which is why the question: is this a good idea or not?

Comment: Are you sure React tries to freeze the state? I seem to be able to change the state as I want.. even though it should always be done through `setState` or `React.Addons.update`.

Comment: @andrerpena - don't know if state is frozen, but have experienced `this.state.obj.atr = val;` not take - from that I concluded that `state.obj` was probably frozen. I know in my Stores that I freeze the data before handing it out to ensure that the Store is responsible for data manipulation, so was inferring the practice on others.